# Alteryx Designer Problem with IF Statement

Tags: if-statement, alteryx

can anyone see a problem with this IF Statement. I get an error while I run in Alteryx.

if !isnull([Opening Balance Total]) then [Opening Balance Total] or

if !IsNull([Closing Balance Total]) then [Closing Balance Total] else ""

endif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "or" needs to be an "else", and you'll need another Endif also... here are these mods, also with indentation to make it more clear:

```
If !IsNull([Opening Balance Total]) then
    [Opening Balance Total]
else 
    if !IsNull([Closing Balance Total]) then
        [Closing Balance Total]
    else
        ""
    endif
endif
```

Comment: Thank you! you're awesome, have great weekend.